# JavaScript: Store a function call in a variable / object

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's an easy way to define a function call inside an object. I know `eval()` works for this purpose but I'm trying to avoid it if possible. This is my scenario:

```
function my_function(val) { console.log("The value is " + val) }
const my_object = {"a": "nothing", "b": 0, "c": my_function("this")}
my_object.c();
```

What I'd like to happen is when you call `my_object.c()`, it runs `my_function()` with the given parameters at that moment. What understandably happens is that `c` gets its value from the return of the function once when the script starts up.

What works as intended is defining it as `"c": function() { my_function("this") }` instead: It works but looks really ugly. Is there a simpler way of writing that, to work the same way but include only the name of the function being called?

Comment: You're looking for [*getter* and *setter* methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: less ugly: `c: () => my_function(“this”)`

Comment: You might be looking for method syntax? `"c"() { my_function("this"); }`

Comment: "*include only the name of the function being called*" - no, you also need to include the values of the arguments that you want to pass into the call (`"this"`). Or you need to pass them when calling `c` (`my_object.c("this");`), in which case you just need to store the function itself in the object: `"c": my_function,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking to do is `bind`.

```
const my_object = {
  c: my_function.bind(this, 'this'),
};
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: That was it, thanks! I used `bind(this)` before, for some reason it didn't click that I should try it here as well. Works the same way but is a lot better to look at.

Comment: Probably don't want that semi-colon on a prop definition, though.

Comment: Sure, @ParkingMaster, depending on whether you want it to compile. :-)